# Responsive image resizing/cropping with CSS/Javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to recreate a responsive image resizer/cropper as in the newsslider at https://www.djhardwell.com/ . 
I have tried to recreate the code with the DOM-explorer, but it is not working.

It doesn't even show the image (image does show up when set in body so path is correctly). I did not find a resizer/cropper like this anywhere else, this one looks really nice. This much code is probably not necessary but this how it is right now:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

<div id="container">

<!--<div id="header">
img src="images/fullhdlogo.png" class="logo"> 
</div> -->
<div id="container1">
<div id="container2">
<div id="container3">
<div id="container4">
<div id="container5">
<div id="container6">
<div id="container7">
<div id="imagecontainer" style="background-image: url (images/fullhdlogo.png);>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html    {
    margin:             0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;  
 }

body    {
margin:             0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 #container {

 }

  #header   {

width:              200px;
height:             100vh;  
background-color:   #62EF7F;



 }
 #container1{
  position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width:  100%;
 height: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box; 
 }

 #container2{
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width:  100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility:hidden;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box; 
 }
 #container3{
 position: relative;
 width:  100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;    
   }  

   #container4{

position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
top: 60px;
left: 0;
bottom: 40px;
padding-right: 5px;
width: 66%;     
   }

   #container5 {

   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;  
 -o-box-sizing: content-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing:content-box;   
  overflow: hidden;
 background-color: inherit;

 }
 #container6{

 position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
  background-color:inherit; 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;         
  }

  #container7{

 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;
 display: block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;

 }

  imagecontainer {


  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;

 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking a question, we expect you to abide by some rules. First of all: Format your code nicely! If possible, provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Second, seperate your HTML from your CSS. Third and possibly most important of all: explain your problem: if the link goes dead, no one will ever understand your question as it stands now. Provide details: what exactly do you want? Back on topic: take a look at `background-size` and more specifically the values `contain` and `cover`.

Comment: I don't see any resizer or cropper on the provided link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the resizer/cropper problem, I'd look into [`background-size:cover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover).  From there, you'd just need a regular slider that changes background images.

Comment: *you'd just need a regular slider that changes background images* How do you do that? That's not an answer.

Comment: Actually, he didn't ask for a slider at all.  He just asked about resizer/cropper which I answered.  I just assumed he might need one later on.